# Group by month and week based on datetime column which will group by first of every month or week

Tags: sql, group-by

Need to Group by month and week, based on a datetime column which will group by first of every month or week, values need to be averaged.

Currently using query which gives no result. Please help me on this!

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0), AVG(Actual), AVG(Planned)
FROM  #Table1
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Date]), 0)
```

Sample table data, and expected result for Group by Month:

[image]

Comment: which dmbs and which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear but in real time situation, we extract the monthly average and here is some sort of solution that I do (Assuming this is for MS SQL Server):

```
DECLARE @YourTable Table([DateCol] DATETIME, [Actual] NUMERIC(10,2), [Planned] NUMERIC(10,2))

INSERT INTO @YourTable ([DateCol], [Actual], [Planned])
VALUES
('01-05-2016 07:00:01',3.1,2.7),
('01-05-2016 19:00:01',2.9,2.7),
('03-05-2016 07:00:01',3.2,2.7),
('03-05-2016 07:00:01',3.4,2.7),
('05-06-2016 07:00:01',3.2,2.7),
('07-06-2016 07:00:01',2.6,2.7),
('07-06-2016 07:00:01',3.2,2.7)



DECLARE @begin DATETIME, 
        @End DATETIME

SELECT  @begin = MIN([DateCol]), @End = MAX([DateCol])
FROM    @YourTable


-- For Monthly avg.
SET @begin = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@begin),0)
SET @End = DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@End),0))

--SELECT @begin,@End

;WITH Months
AS
(
    SELECT  @begin DateRange
    UNION   ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH,1,DateRange)
    FROM    Months
    WHERE   DateRange < @End
)
SELECT  m.DateRange, DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,m.DateRange)+1,0)) [DateRangeEnd],AVG([Actual]) [AvgActual],AVG([Planned]) [AvgPlanned]
FROM    @YourTable y 
        INNER JOIN Months m
            ON y.DateCol BETWEEN m.DateRange AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,m.DateRange)+1,0))
GROUP   BY m.DateRange,DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,m.DateRange)+1,0))
```

I make @Begin and @End as my report parameters so that user can decides the range.